# How to setup cri-o with kubeadm and kubelet on Kubernetes 1.18.2?

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm

I am relatively new to Kubernetes and although that I am able to launch the master node (join workers / master nodes) by using the default socket (/var/run/dockershim.sock) I would like to use the cri-o socket (unix:///var/run/crio/crio.sock).

I have been reading any documentation that I was able to find but none it seems to be working for me.

I am running Kubernetes on Centos7.

CRI-O:

```
# crio version
Version:       1.18.2
GitCommit:     754d46b53595cf2db74d2a73a685d573910b814e
GitTreeState:  clean
BuildDate:     2020-06-25T09:23:58Z
GoVersion:     go1.13.6
Compiler:      gc
Platform:      linux/amd64
Linkmode:      dynamic
```

Docker:

```
# docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           19.03.12
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.13.10
 Git commit:        48a66213fe
 Built:             Mon Jun 22 15:46:54 2020
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          19.03.12
  API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.13.10
  Git commit:       48a66213fe
  Built:            Mon Jun 22 15:45:28 2020
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.2.13
  GitCommit:        7ad184331fa3e55e52b890ea95e65ba581ae3429
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc10
  GitCommit:
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.18.0
  GitCommit:        fec3683
```

I follow the official documentation [Container runtimes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/container-runtimes/), but I also found the repo in GitHub which describes a bit different the configuration [CRI-O (GitHub)](https://github.com/cri-o/cri-o/blob/master/tutorials/setup.md).

I tried installing cri-o from source but also from the rpm. Both times the result is the same:

```
Jun 25 13:31:19 hostname kubelet[23665]: I0625 13:31:19.700722   23665 server.go:417] Version: v1.18.2
Jun 25 13:31:19 hostname kubelet[23665]: I0625 13:31:19.701175   23665 plugins.go:100] No cloud provider specified.
Jun 25 13:31:19 hostname kubelet[23665]: I0625 13:31:19.701208   23665 server.go:837] Client rotation is on, will bootstrap in background
Jun 25 13:31:19 hostname kubelet[23665]: F0625 13:31:19.701323   23665 server.go:274] failed to run Kubelet: unable to load bootstrap kubeconfig: stat /etc/kubernetes/bootstrap-kubelet.conf: no such file or directory
Jun 25 13:31:19 hostname systemd[1]: kubelet.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=255/n/a
Jun 25 13:31:19 hostname systemd[1]: Unit kubelet.service entered failed state.
Jun 25 13:31:19 hostname systemd[1]: kubelet.service failed.
```

From the little that I know if I remember correctly this file `/etc/kubernetes/bootstrap-kubelet.conf` is autogenerated when kubeadm is started.

Configurations that I have applied.

10-kubeadm.conf:

```
# cat /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf
[Service]
Environment="KUBELET_KUBECONFIG_ARGS=--bootstrap-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/bootstrap-kubelet.conf --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf"
Environment="KUBELET_CONFIG_ARGS=--config=/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml"
# This is a file that "kubeadm init" and "kubeadm join" generate at runtime, populating the KUBELET_KUBEADM_ARGS variable dynamically
EnvironmentFile=-/var/lib/kubelet/kubeadm-flags.env
# This is a file that the user can use for overrides of the kubelet args as a last resort. Preferably,
# the user should use the .NodeRegistration.KubeletExtraArgs object in the configuration files instead.
# KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS should be sourced from this file.
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/kubelet
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/kubelet $KUBELET_KUBECONFIG_ARGS $KUBELET_CONFIG_ARGS $KUBELET_KUBEADM_ARGS $KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS
```

01-log-level.conf:

```
# cat /etc/crio/crio.conf.d/01-log-level.conf
[crio.runtime]
log_level = "info"
```

01-cgroup-manager.conf:

```
# cat /etc/crio/crio.conf.d/01-cgroup-manager.conf
[crio.runtime]
cgroup_manager = "systemd"
```

kubelet:

```
# cat /etc/default/kubelet
KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS=--feature-gates="AllAlpha=false,RunAsGroup=true" --container-runtime=remote --cgroup-driver=systemd --container-runtime-endpoint='unix:///var/run/crio/crio.sock' --runtime-request-timeout=5m
```

I can verify that the cri-o socket is working as I can pull the images from my repo:

```
# kubeadm config images pull --image-repository=my.private.repo --kubernetes-version=v1.18.2 --cri-socket unix:///var/run/crio/crio.sock
W0625 13:53:17.554897   29936 configset.go:202] WARNING: kubeadm cannot validate component configs for API groups [kubelet.config.k8s.io kubeproxy.config.k8s.io]
[config/images] Pulled my.private.repo/kube-apiserver:v1.18.2
[config/images] Pulled my.private.repo/kube-controller-manager:v1.18.2
[config/images] Pulled my.private.repo/kube-scheduler:v1.18.2
[config/images] Pulled my.private.repo/kube-proxy:v1.18.2
[config/images] Pulled my.private.repo/pause:3.2
[config/images] Pulled my.private.repo/etcd:3.4.3-0
[config/images] Pulled my.private.repo/coredns:1.6.7
```

I have spend 3 days and I am not able to figure it out. Can someone with more experience provide more info?

**Update:** adding init command:

```
kubeadm init \
        --upload-certs \
        --cri-socket=unix:///var/run/crio/crio.sock \ # /var/run/dockershim.sock 
        --node-name=master-prime \
        --image-repository=my.private.repo \
        --pod-network-cidr=10.96.0.0/16 \
        --kubernetes-version=v1.18.2 \
        --control-plane-endpoint=IP:PORT \
        --apiserver-cert-extra-sans=IP \
        --apiserver-advertise-address=IP
```

Comment: Did you create those kubelet configs by hand, or were the written by [`kubeadm join`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/kubeadm-join/#join-workflow)? Because that's the step which emits the `bootstrap-kubelet.conf`, containing the join-token as authentication, which is then used to issue `kubelet` long-term credentials

Comment: I created the config files I created them by hand. At least this is what I thought I should do based on documentation no?

Comment: is the rest of that sentence "and then I ran `kubeadm join`", because that's what I'm trying to get at -- whether you created those config files and expected the Node to spring to life, OR you created those config files, then ran kubeadm join, and things are still not working

Comment: I have implemented both solutions. Either with a configuration file or using the flags. I don’t have access to my laptop but I will update my question tomorrow with a sample. This the master primary node in the cluster. And it fails to be launched with cri-o. It is not a master secondary node that it is joining the cluster.

Comment: @mdaniel please see the update on my question.

Comment: Could you take a look at this [tutorial](https://kubevirt.io/2019/KubeVirt_k8s_crio_from_scratch.html) about configurating cri-o and follow up [tutorial](https://kubevirt.io/2019/KubeVirt_k8s_crio_from_scratch_installing_kubernetes.html) for installation? Maybe you find something useful here. Additionally what CNI do you use? Have you configured your cidr in CRI-O configuration file?

Comment: Still the error persist no matter what I do. It might be a bug I have raised a ticket on the crio team. I will update as soon as I have more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been some time that I raised this question and I never answered it. I completely forgot.

The problem with me was that I am launching the cluster on offline cluster.

I managed to figured it out and the CRI-O team asked me to documented in case that other would try to do the same thing.

The full configuration and steps can be found in the official GitHub page: [Running kubeadm in an off line network](https://github.com/cri-o/cri-o/blob/master/tutorials/kubeadm.md#running-kubeadm-in-an-off-line-network)

Hope that this helps someone else in future.

Comment: Thanks , --crio-socket supported by the kubeadm from command line or not?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question 100%. If you mean through `kubeadm` command line like `kubeadm init` then yes it does. Official documentation [kubeadm init](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/kubeadm-init/).

Comment: Thanks. If I don't pickup the runtime using --crio-socket, when there is docker and crio socket coexisting in the same node, who will be picked up as runtime?

Comment: It want start :). It will complain the kubeadm that detects multiple sockets and you need to choose one with the flag that you provided above `--crio-socket`.